# Novel where a group of people (including a "vampire") go to investigate an object in space

Tags: story-identification, novel

A group of people sent out to investigate an anomaly and one of them was a "vampire" (but actually more of an enhanced human). When they get there we learn that it's either a ship or an hunk of space rock. As they are searching it the come to find out the whole thing is really "alive".

If it helps I think that the title started with the letter C

Comment: Blindsight. It doesn’t start with “C”, though

Comment: Awesome thanks i don't know why I thought it did. It's been a long time since I read it

Answer (score 20):

### Blindsight

To quote from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindsight_(Watts_novel)):

> Years afterwards, a comet-surveying satellite stumbles across a radio
>   transmission originating from a comet, subsequently named
>   ‘Burns-Caulfield’. This tight-beam broadcast is directed to an unknown
>   location and in fact does not intersect the Earth at any point. As
>   this is the first opportunity to learn more about the
>   extraterrestrials, three waves of ships are sent out: the first being
>   light probes shot out for an as-soon-as-possible flyby of the comet,
>   then a wave of heavier but better-equipped probes, and **finally a
>   manned ship, the Theseus.**
>
> Theseus is propelled by an antimatter reactor and captained by an
>   artificial intelligence. It carries a crew of five cutting-edge
>   transhuman hyper-specialists of **whom one is a genetically-reincarnated
>   vampire and acts as the nominal mission commander.**

We’ve got our mysterious rock, our “vampire,” and so forth. It doesn’t start with the letter C, though.